# How to make fixed table header scroll horizontally in sync with tbody data?

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following table with a fixed header. I want the header to be scrollable horizontally insync with the  data? so that the header also scrolls horizontally when the user scrolls the tbody data horizontally. Is it possible to do that?

Note: I will be creating the table columns and header dynamically.. so sometime i can only have 2 columns sometimes 10 columns with 10 headers

[Fiddle  code](http://jsfiddle.net/9t8fmp16/1/)

```
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>head1</th>
            <th>head2</th>
            <th>head3</th>
            <th>head4</th>
              <th>head4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>

            <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
            <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
            <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
            <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
             <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
            <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
            <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
            <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
             <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
            <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
            <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
            <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
              <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
            <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
            <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
            <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
             <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

table tbody
{
    display: block;
}
table thead
{
    display: block;
    overflow:auto;
}

table tbody 
{
   overflow: auto;
   height: 100px;
   position:absolute;
}

th
{
    width: 72px;
}
```

Comment: please write some code to do that

Comment: @Ejay-there is code already posted   and also in fiddle link

Comment: I think you want something called "sticky table header", and the easiest way to implement it is to use a jQuery plug-in: http://www.fixedheadertable.com/

Answer (score 1):

The only way to sync them is to listen to the `scroll` event, and update the header position accordingly. Something like this (assuming `window` is the container):

```
var headerEl = document.getElementById('yourHeadElement'); // or w/e
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){
    var offset = window.pageXOffset;
    headerEl.style.marginLeft = (-offset) + 'px';
    // alternatively:
    // headerEl.style.transform = 'translate3d('+ (-offset) +'px,0,0);';
}, false);
```

Note: You can even update the position by the `transform` property with `translate`/`translate3d` if you'd like to as well (instead of marginLeft).

If your container is not window, you will have to rely on the `DOMElement.scrollLeft` property. Happy coding!