# Table with Fixed header in Elm - how to sync the header with the body both horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css, elm

I have a table where I don't know in advance the number of columns and number of rows. I need:

- fixed header
- horizontal scroll
- vertical scroll

The main issue I am having is that the table header is not moving in sync horizontally. In JavaScript, I could do that, for example in [How to make fixed table header scroll horizontally in sync with tbody data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828788/how-to-make-fixed-table-header-scroll-horizontally-in-sync-with-tbody-data). 
How can I make it work in Elm?

I also have some other issues:

- the header cell not being the same width as the body cells.
- In this example https://ellie-app.com/hS8kFyKRza1/0, I want only the first 3 columns to be displayed and the rest to show when scrolling horizontally, and the table to move in sync with the header when scrolling both ways.

If I can't do without JavaScript, I would appreciate some pointers on how I should set my ports and what the JS code should be.

Answer (score 2):

If your browser support requirements allow for it, the way we've done this is to use CSS [`position: sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Sticky_positioning) on the `th` elements in the header row. Older browsers (including IE 11) don't support this, but as a progressive enhancement it works well, since unsupported browsers just don't get the sticky header effect.